# Как узнать пользователь использует gpt или mbr?

Tags: c#, windows, mbr, gpt

Как с помощью с# можно узнать, для загрузки системы пользователь использует  gpt или mbr?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18501148/12888024

Comment: @aepot, там вопрос совершенно про другое - как именно отформатировано конкретное блочное устройство. здесь же вопрос гораздо шире - с какого именно блочного устройства был запущен загрузчик. а если автора вопроса к тому же интересует ситуация, когда последовательно запускаемых загрузчиков может быть больше одного, и располагаться они могут на разных блочных устройствах, то ответ на вопрос превращается уже в маленькое исследование.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin _с какого именно блочного устройства был запущен загрузчик_ - для gpt эта информация в bios, а не на диске, верно?

Comment: @aepot, насколько я себе это представляю, данная информация вообще нигде не фиксируется. о том, откуда загружаться **по умолчанию** - по сети или с локального устройства - хранится, конечно, в bios-е. а вот что именно использовалось для **текущей** загрузки - знает, вероятно, только пользователь.